# Why is the traction vector dependent on just normal vector instead of the geometry of the entire cuting surface?

Tags: classical-mechanics, continuum-mechanics

[image]

Given a continuum  G with surface forces on its surface S being cut arbitrarily (not necessarily by a plane) it is natural that the traction vector at any point along the cut depends on the cut itself. If the forces are represented as tractions T across the surface of the object, Let the cutting surface be C, the surface of the first half of the cut object as S1, and the surface of the second half S2. In the image, the light blue surface would be C, the dark blue would be S1 on the left and S2 on the right. Then

$$\oint_{C\cup S_1}  \vec{T}dS = m \vec{a}_{cg}$$

where m is the mass of the whole object and cg is the center of gravity for the whole object. Thus it is natural that the traction field on C depends on the geometry of C. But I don't understand how to show that the traction at a point is strictly dependent on the normal at that point, rather than the entire cut.

Comment: The fact that the stress vector at a point of a cut depends only on the normal to the cut at that point is known as "Cauchy's postulate". As its name indicates, it is a postulate although it can be proven under some regularity hypothesis: Cauchy's postulate then becomes Noll's theorem. See e.g. these lecture notes  (http://home.iitk.ac.in/~ag/ME321/stress.pdf) and if you have (significantly) more patience these ones (http://mcg.ida.upmc.fr/Telechargements/Seppecher-Article-1.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

The state of stress within the material varies from location to location, and is thus local.  On a small enough scale, every cut can be represented by its tangent plane.  The Cauchy stress  relationship gives the traction vector on that tangent plane.